# Tweepy error 'API' object has no attribute 'me'

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to run the code from https://github.com/CreepyD246/Twitter-Reply-Bot/blob/main/TwitterReplyBot.py on Replit.

```
#Importing modules/libraries
import tweepy
import time
import os

# Initialization code
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(os.getenv("key2"),os.getenv("skey2"))
auth.set_access_token(os.getenv("token2"),os.getenv("stoken2"))
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Some important variables which will be used later
bot_id = int(api.me().id_str)
#Other things after
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
bot_id = int(api.me().id_str)
AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'me'
```

I don't find anything in the Tweepy's documentation about `API.me()` so what's wrong?
The Tweepy version is 4.1.0.

Comment: It existed in v3: https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.me. See https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v4.0.0/changelog.html#breaking-changes.

Comment: So what should I use instead  to get my id ?

Comment: I'd suggest reading the changelogs to see if they recommend an alternative, or updated API docs to see what's available now.

Answer (score 5):

[Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) removed `API.me`.
You can use [`API.verify_credentials`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/api.html#tweepy.API.verify_credentials) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Tweepy v4.0.0 removed `API.me` use `API.get_user`
That is the replacement for now

Answer (score 0):

yes **api.get_user** is the replacement in tweepy v4.0.0

Comment: API.get_user is not a replacement for API.me

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me `api.get_user(screen_name="replaceWithYourTwitterUsername")`